# extract pattern data using gawk/awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a input text like below:

> ```
>  10779: (255,255,  0,255) #FFFF00 yellow
>    338: (255,238,125,255) #FFEE00 srgba(255,238,125,1)
>    180: (238,221,  0,255) #EEDD00 srgba(238,221,0,1)
>  ....
> ```

I wish the output is

> ```
>  255,255,0,255    
>  255,238,125,255    
>  238,211,0,255
> ```

How to extract this data from the input using gawk/awk? I've tried this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS=\"[:,()]\"};{print $3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

but this gives me space between the data, e.g.
255 255  0 255

Comment: You might find it easier to understand how to do this using regular expressions in a language like Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.  Are you open to a solution in a language other than awk?

Comment: Set `OFS=","` so that fields are separated by commas on output.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your input I am guessing this might work

```
awk -F'[()]' '{gsub(/ /,"",$2); print $2}' file
255,255,0,255
255,238,125,255
238,221,0,255
```

Comment: it didn't went through

Comment: invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: @emilywuq - sure you running gawk?

Comment: sorry, you are right, I guess it is awk on my windows not configured right. Can you explain the gsub part?

Comment: @emilywuq, in this case `gsub` does a global substitution of space chars with empty chars in field 2

Comment: You do not need the `$2` since `gsub`removes all the spaces, so this is ok: `awk -F'[()]' '{gsub(/ /,""); print $2}'`

Comment: @jotne, you nitpicker ;-) All said and done you're an `awk` champ

Comment: @1_CR I always try to get my `awk` as short and exact as possible ;)

Comment: @jotne, short and exact as possible sounds suspiciously like `sed` ;-). In any case, thanks for keeping us journeymen `awk` practitioners honest

Comment: @1_CR `sed` is god for lots of stuff, but it tends to be very hard to read and easy to miss a `.`. That is why I like `awk`, but correct tool for correct job :)

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/\((.*?)\)/)'
```

If you donot want those spaces, then:

```
perl -lne '$a=$1 if(/\((.*?)\)/);$a=~s/ //g;print $a'
```

Awk:

```
awk '{a=index($0,"(");b=index($0,")");a++;b--;print substr($0,a,b-a)}'
```

[Tested](http://ideone.com/ZEdg70)

Comment: how to do it using awk/gawk?

Comment: for removing the spaces you can anyhow use the gsub part by storing the substr in a string and then remove the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[(#]' 'gsub(/[ )]/,"")&&$0=$2' file
255,255,0,255
255,238,125,255
238,221,0,255
```

Comment: I want to get rid of space before 0

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution, for variety:

```
sed -E 's/^.+\(([^)]+)\).+$/\1/; s/ //g' file
```

Or, one step at a time, with `cut` and `tr`:

```
cut -d '(' -f 2 file | cut -d ')' -f 1 | tr -d ' '
```

Comment: alas, it is still producing a different result than awk-based solutions (with the second line using GNU sed)

Comment: @1_CR: Thanks for troubleshooting; fixed now.

Comment: +1, unlike the awk solutions, it leaves non-qualifying lines untampered